# How to sort a map by a value?

Tags: elixir

I have defined a map like below:

```
%{
      "24fe6042-2673-4713-8052-5c06e5ddcce8" => %Parameter{
        index: 1,
        name: "b",
      },
      "28ab6e8b-95b8-4123-af5d-5e988071c383" => %Parameter{
        index: 0,
        name: "a",
      }
    },
```

how can I sort the map into an array based on the `index` inside the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Enum.sort/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#sort/2)

```
Enum.sort(input, fn
  {_, %Parameter{index: i1}}, {_, %Parameter{index: i2}} -> i1 <= i2
end)
```

or (less idiomatic, uses `Access` behaviour on each iteration)

```
Enum.sort(input, fn
  {_, v1}, {_, v2} -> v1.index <= v2.index
end)
```

I am not sure I understood “sort the map into an array” wording, but if you want to discard keys and get an array of values, use [`Map.values/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Map.html#values/1).

```
input
|> Map.values()
|> Enum.sort(fn
  %Parameter{index: i1}, %Parameter{index: i2} -> i1 <= i2
end)
```